# Having issue with deploying app to the app engine

Tags: deployment, google-app-engine

I am getting following error while deploying my app to app engine from my local machine. I used the following command in terminal:

```
 ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy api.n**.********.com/app.yaml --version api-**t
```

I have used '*' to hide the actual letters for security reasons. I am getting the following error when I run the above command:

```
  ERROR: (gcloud.app) Invalid choice: 'deploy api.n**.********.com/app.yaml --version'.
Maybe you meant:
  gcloud app deploy

Showing 1 out of 53 suggestions.

To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS
```

It was working till yesterday night. But it is not working today. How to fix this issue? Kindly help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Regards,
Janarthanan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your command line arguments by spaces.

In particular you need a space between `deploy` and `api.n...` and a space between `...yaml` and `--version`.

What you appear to have used *looks* like a space but is likely some other Unicode character. Perhaps you copied and pasted this command line from some web page which inserted nonstandard spaces for some reason?

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. Yes, I removed those existing spaces and typed again. Now it works fine. I had copied from my notes editor. It could be some other unicode character as you mentioned.Thanks again!